# Nginx reverse cache 301 redirects (permanent)

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, 301-redirect

Is it possible to have Nginx cache all `301` redirect requests for `proxy_pass`?

For example:

Request #1: Client A requests /some/path -> sent to `proxy_pass` -> results in 301 redirect to `/some/other/path` -> nginx caches this response since it's a 301 redirect.

Request #2: Client B requests /some/path -> nginx returns cached 301 redirect to `/some/other/path`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found that @Michael's answer got me most of the way there, but when I turned on `proxy_cache`, it would automatically cache files with `Expires` and `Cache-Control`. So I ended up with this solution.

```
proxy_cache_path /tmp/nginx levels=1:2 keys_zone=main-cache:8m max_size=1000m inactive=600m;
proxy_temp_path /tmp/nginx/tmp;
proxy_cache main-cache;
proxy_cache_valid 301 60m;
proxy_cache_key "$scheme://$host$request_uri";
proxy_ignore_headers X-Accel-Expires Expires Cache-Control;
```

Comment: That's what a cache _does_. Nowhere did you ever mention that you didn't want anything else cached.

Answer (score 8):

nginx already can cache 301 redirects. You can change the amount of time they are cached with the [proxy_cache_valid](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_cache_valid) directive:

```
proxy_cache_valid 301 365d; # Cache permanent redirects for a whole year
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want redirect all, you could use this way:

```
location / {
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080/VirtualHostBase/https/$server_name:443/some/path/VirtualHostRoot;
}
```

Your examples could need the combination of `rewrite` and `proxy_pass`:

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /VirtualHostBase/https/$server_name:443/some/path/VirtualHostRoot$1 break;
  proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

*Warning*: you have got different rewrite `redirect` effect: `break` returns 301 instead `permanent` returns 302.

**EDIT**
Upstream this module/s you need use `proxy_cache_valid` diretive:

```
proxy_cache_valid  301 1h;
```

*Warning*, upstream cache-related directives have priority over proxy_cache_valid value, in particular the order is:

1. X-Accel-Expires
2. Expires/Cache-Control
3. proxy_cache_valid

Reference: [HttpProxyModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule), [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite)