# Running sinatra program [Kibana] behind nginx reverse proxy in web directory

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, sinatra

I'm trying to get Kibana to run behind nginx within a specific web directory. Or, put another way, I'm trying to have nginx reverse proxy `http://example.com/kibana` to `http://localhost:5601/`, which is where the Kibana sinatra app is running.

I've started Kibana with an init script, and if I `curl` the `localhost` url from the server, I get the expected response. However, navigating to `http://example.com/kibana/` gives me the message of `Sinatra doesn’t know this ditty.` and a suggestion that `/kibana/` should do something. Presumably, this is a routing issue.

My nginx config is simply this:

```
server {                                                                                                                                                       
    listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied                                                                                          
    listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6                                                                                                   

    root /var/www;                                                                                                                                             
    index index.html index.htm;                                                                                                                                

    # Make site accessible from http://localhost/                                                                                                              
    server_name _;                                                                                                                                             

    location / {                                                                                                                                               
        # First attempt to serve request as file, then                                                                                                         
        # as directory, then fall back to index.html                                                                                                           
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;                                                                                                                      
        # Uncomment to enable naxsi on this location                                                                                                           
        # include /etc/nginx/naxsi.rules                                                                                                                       
    }                                                                                                                                                          
    location /kibana/ {                                                                                                                                     
        proxy_pass  http://localhost:5601;                                                                                                                     
        proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;                                                                  
        proxy_redirect off;                                                                                                                                    
        proxy_buffering off;                                                                                                                                   
        proxy_set_header        Host            $host;                                                                                                         
        proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;                                                                                                  
        proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;                                                                                    
    }                                                                                                                                                          
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have one modification on the previous answer.

```
proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5601;
```

Replace by

```
proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5601/;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this: https://serverfault.com/a/379679/82682 (eventually replace '/foo/Kibana-0.2.0')

```
location /kibana {
    # rewrite before passing to proxy
    rewrite /kibana/(.*) /$1  break;
    proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:5601;
    # include nginx' proxy-defaults
    include proxy_params;

    # serve static stuff directly from the static-directory
    location /kibana/favicon.ico {
        alias /foo/Kibana-0.2.0/static/favicon.ico;
    }
    location /kibana/images {
        alias /foo/Kibana-0.2.0/static/images;
    }
    location /kibana/lib {
        alias /foo/Kibana-0.2.0/static/lib;
    }
}
```