# Kibana4 + nginx reverse proxy using location /kibana4/ = Not Found 404

Tags: nginx, kibana

I'm trying to setup **Kibana4** with nginx reverse proxy, with partial success so far. Here is my config related to Kibana:

```
server {
  listen 82;
  server_name ${HOSTNAME};

  set $kibana kibana.docker;

  location /kibana4/ {
    proxy_pass              http://$kibana:5601;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        Referer "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_connect_timeout   150;
    proxy_send_timeout      100;
    proxy_read_timeout      100;
    proxy_buffers           16 64k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    client_max_body_size    256k;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
  }
}
```

In that case if I go to `http://localhost:82/kibana4/` I will get **Not Found 404**

But if I replace `location /kibana4/` with `location /`, everything work well - of course URL changes to `http://localhost:82` in that case.

I have found a few other topics related to similar problem, e.g.:

[Running sinatra program [Kibana] behind nginx reverse proxy in web directory](https://serverfault.com/questions/434241/running-sinatra-program-kibana-behind-nginx-reverse-proxy-in-web-directory)

but the solutions described there don't work for me. I even tried this config:

```
server {
  listen 82;
  server_name ${HOSTNAME};

  set $kibana kibana.docker;

  location /kibana4 {
    proxy_pass              http://$kibana:5601/;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        Referer "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_connect_timeout   150;
    proxy_send_timeout      100;
    proxy_read_timeout      100;
    proxy_buffers           16 64k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    client_max_body_size    256k;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
  }
}
```

It starts proxy to `kibana.docker` host, but the problem is that all URL are rewritten to the same kibana loading page. It causes that any CSS or JavaScript file cannot be loaded properly.

**My question is:** does anyone know what can be wrong here? Does anyone run successfully Kibana4 from a different than server root location? I would appreciate your help.

Comment: Is kibana running on http://kibana.docker:5601/ or http://kibana.docker:5601/kibana4 ?

Comment: Thank you @HD. for enlightening me. Your question showed me what was the problem. Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you HD. for your question below my previous post - it was very enlightening. It helped me realize what was the problem. I always forget that location part is also passed to proxy, that's why it has to be rewritten in my case. Here is what the correct config should look like:

```
  location ~ ^/kibana4/(.*)$ {
    rewrite /kibana4/(.*) /$1  break;
    proxy_pass              http://$kibana:5601;
    proxy_set_header        Host $host;
    proxy_set_header        Referer "";
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_http_version      1.1;
    proxy_connect_timeout   150;
    proxy_send_timeout      100;
    proxy_read_timeout      100;
    proxy_buffers           16 64k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    client_max_body_size    256k;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;
  }
```

It also explains why the `location /` setting is working correctly if there is no `rewrite` part. After adding `rewrite`, only the rest part is passed to proxy and it works like a charm.

Thank you once again, lesson learned :-)

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but I wanted to leave a satisfactory solution for Apache here since I can't find them. The thing that made proxying from a subdirectory for me work was adding a trailing slash after the ProxyPass directory:

```
ProxyPass /kibana/ http://localhost:5601/
ProxyPassReverse /kibana/ http://localhost:5601/
```

See here:

http://www.marathon-studios.com/blog/solved-kibana-5-not-loading-404ing-when-reverse-proxying-in-a-subdirectory/

Answer (score 0):

As of Kibana 6.3, settings are now available in [kibana.yml](https://github.com/elastic/kibana/blob/81153c2a22d320ea61cc081fc45594a45331a103/config/kibana.yml)

```
server.host: "example.com"
server.basePath: "/tools/kibana"
server.rewriteBasePath: true
```

This will serve the app at http://example.com/tools/kibana with all the links in the Kibana UI