# nginx reverse proxy and rewrite rule

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, rewrite

This [question](https://serverfault.com/a/379679/470818) is actually quite close to my requirement where, the Nginx configuration rewrites the URL for `$1`.

Reproduced here:

```sh
location  /foo {
  rewrite /foo/(.*) /$1  break;
  proxy_pass         http://localhost:3200;
  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host $host;
}
```

Whereas, in my case the original URL may have any number of levels of nesting and query parameters My requirement is to maintain those levels *and* prepend a level.

Examples:

Original URL: `https://apis.demo.com/books/12414`

Desired URL: `http://localhost:3000/prepend/books/12414`

Original URL: `https://apis.demo.com/books/12414?find=meta`

Desired URL: `http://localhost:3000/prepend/books/12414?find=meta`

Original URL: `https://apis.demo.com/library/LIB001/books/12414`

Desired URL: `http://localhost:3000/prepend/library/LIB001/books/12414`

Original URL: `https://apis.demo.com/library/LIB001/books/12414/history`

Desired URL: `http://localhost:3000/prepend/library/LIB001/books/12414/history`

How do we achieve this?