# nginx Proxy Manager Custom Locations

Tags: nginx

Ultimately I intend to configure nginx to proxy content from web services on different hosts. As currently set up I'm using nginx Proxy Manager with nginx in Docker containers. To exclude the complexities of web service setup from the issues of configuring the reverse proxy, I have set up web servers with static content.

- I have Apache in a container on the same docker network as the nginx container.
- I have IIS on my workstation.

As you can see from this grab I have nginx successfully set up to proxy my workstation's IIS (not to mention a public DNS entry for my external interface. That's working fine.

[image: IIS proxied by nginx]

These grabs show that the Apache container maps 80 to 8080 on the docker host which is imaginatively named dockerhost, and the browser on my workstation can access both the root document and another document by name.

[image: apache root doc]
[image: apache more doc]

At this point I altered the nginx proxy host definition to define a custom location. *Within* the docker network Apache is on port 80; this is why I've specified 80 rather than 8080.

[image: nginx proxy host definition custom location]

This appears to work.

[image: Browser loads apache root]

...until you try to load some other resource from Apache but get the same content.

[image: Trying to load something other than the root document]

It appears that absolutely anything beginning with `apache/` is mapped to the root document.

[image: anycrap]

At this point I went back and looked for documentation but failed to find anything relevant.

Swapping things around so that nginx proxies IIS and the custom location `iis` points at IIS on my workstation exhibits exactly the same problem, this time with IIS.

### How should this configuration be expressed?

A Proxy Manager based answer is preferable, I have quite a bit to learn before I can use instructions on hacking the nginx config directly.

That said, for diagnostic use, here's the generated config.

```
# ------------------------------------------------------------
# wone.pdconsec.net
# ------------------------------------------------------------
server {
  set $forward_scheme http;
  set $server         "pnuc.lan";
  set $port           80;

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;
  listen 443 ssl http2;
  listen [::]:443 ssl http2;

  server_name wone.pdconsec.net;

  # Let's Encrypt SSL
  include conf.d/include/letsencrypt-acme-challenge.conf;
  include conf.d/include/ssl-ciphers.conf;
  ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-1/fullchain.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/npm-1/privkey.pem;

  access_log /data/logs/proxy-host-1_access.log proxy;
  error_log /data/logs/proxy-host-1_error.log warn;

  location /apache {
    set              $upstream http://apache:80/;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP      $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass       $upstream;

  }

  location / {
    # Proxy!
    include conf.d/include/proxy.conf;
  }

  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
}
```

Comment: hi, any admin panels would be off-topic. However, I would use Nginx as the first contact and then let Nginx decide based on the config, where it should go to.

Comment: I can see the config file, it's in a mapped volume on dockerhost but I don't seem to have edit permission.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since the question was made, but I think you missed to add `$request_uri` to upstream.

```
set              $upstream http://apache:80$request_uri;
```

References:
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_pass
https://dev.to/danielkun/nginx-everything-about-proxypass-2ona
[Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite)

Comment: "It requires information and reference to support the understanding of this answer for verification."

Comment: That's cool, it's ages since I had occasion to want this. But it resurfaced yesterday so your timing is exquisite.

Comment: Hi @PeterWone , I was just guessing... did it actually work?