# Route port 443 to another server iptables

Tags: iptables, routing, proxy

I have 2 servers VPS1 and VPS2

I have a proxy server on VPS2 on port 443

But I can't directly access to VPS2 becuase of GFW for connect to that proxy.

But I can connect to VPS1

I want to setup iptables to route all traffic to port 443 to VPS2

client connect to proxy with ip of VPS1

VPS1 route proxy data to VPS2.

I have a socks5 proxy on vps2 and I want to connect to it via vps1 ip.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite)

Comment: I don't know tbh, I have a socks proxy on vps2 with running on port 443, now I want connect to it with ip of vps1 .

Comment: Im sorry but home and End-User question are not on topic for Serverfault but might be on Superuser