# reverse proxy for subdirectory on another server with wordpress for blog

Tags: nginx, wordpress, cloudflare, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a website and it's working now as

`https://example.com`

Now I want to load my blog as a subdirectory but on another server, it should be loaded as

`https://example.com/blog`

I am using nginx webserver and Cloudflare DNS service, and I know that I should use a reverse proxy for this purpose, but couldn't make it work yet

I need to know, what DNS record I should add and what nginx config I should use

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite)

Comment: thank you for sending this URL, but I couldn't get it working with what was described there

Comment: Cloudflare *is* a reverse proxy.

Comment: thank you, I am using Cloudflare DNS service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after a lot of work on the problem, I found the right answer,
I am on Ubuntu 22, nginx 1.25, the main website is based on Django and the blog is based on WordPress, and these websites are on different servers

first, create an A record for the subdomain, which points to the blog server IP address, for example
A  blog   127.0.0.1

after that, add this to the main website nginx config file

```
location  /blog/ {
    proxy_pass http://blog.example.com/;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;
    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host blog.example.com;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
    proxy_set_header Connection “”;
}
```

and finally, create a config file for the blog website on the blog server

```
server {
    server_name www.example.com/blog;
    root /var/www/blog;
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/blog.access.log  main;


    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "https://www.example.com";
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST';
    add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' 'true';
    add_header Access-Control-Allow-Headers User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type;
    add_header 'Referrer-Policy' 'origin';


    location /wp-admin/ {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$args;
    }


    location / {
        root /var/www/blog;
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        try_files $uri $uri /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 120;
        fastcgi_pass_header Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_pass_header Cookie;
        fastcgi_ignore_headers Cache-Control Expires Set-Cookie;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_param  PATH_TRANSLATED    $document_root$fastcgi_path_info;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 404 60m;
        fastcgi_cache_valid 200 60m;
        fastcgi_max_temp_file_size 4m;
        fastcgi_cache_use_stale updating;
    }

    listen 80;
    listen 443 ssl;
}
```

please pay attention, your WordPress admin URL will be:

```
https://blog.example.com
```

while the blog front will be accessible via

```
https://www.example.com/blog
```

so you need to add this line of codes to the WordPress wp-config.php file

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'https://www.example.com/blog' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'https://blog.example.com' );
```

**Known issue:**
With this configuration, you can't use WordPress templates that are based on elementor page builder, because when you try to edit a page in the admin, as the elementor is loaded in the front, you will get a cookie error, I couldn't fix this yet,
but with non elementor templates like the Jannah theme, it's fine and there is no problem with the configuration