# Nginx TCP Forwarding only for subdomain

Tags: nginx, debian, email-server, subdomain, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have Debian 12 box on Hetzner running Cowmail and Nginx.
Cowmail runs under mail.mydomain.com subdomain (mydomain.com is placeholder) on ports 8069 and 44369.

What I am trying to do is:

1. Serve static html when visiting mydomain.com (served by nginx).
2. Redirect ports 443, 80 to 44369, 8069 respectively when vising mail subdomain.

Currently when I try to vising mydomain.com it still redirects ports.

/etc/nginx.conf (Comments removed, the only diffrence from default file is include at the end)

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
        worker_connections 768;
}

http {
        sendfile on;
        tcp_nopush on;
        types_hash_max_size 2048;
        include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
        default_type application/octet-stream;
        ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dr>
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        gzip on;
        include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
        include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

include /etc/nginx/tcpconf.d/*;
```

/etc/nginx/tcpconf.d/lb

```
stream {
    upstream web_server {
        server mail.mydomain.com:44369;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        proxy_pass web_server;
    }
}
```

/etc/nginx/sites-avalible/default (comments removed, simlink in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/)

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /home/www-none/public;
    index index.html ;

    server_name _;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}

server {
    server_name www.mydomain.com;
    return 301 $scheme://mydomain.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    root /home/www-mydomain-com/public; 
    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
}
```

Additional notes:

- Server will host multiple domains, so that's why it will return page from /home/www-none/public when requested directly by IP.
- SSL certificates generated by Let's Encrypt using certbot.
- Certificates for mail.mydomain.com and mydomain.com are diffrent.
- mydomain.com website is stored in /home/www-mydomain-com/public, Nginx DOES have access to it, because user www-data has been added to www-mydomain.com and www-none groups.
- I am using this TCP stream method, because when using 'classic' reverse proxy nginx replaces ssl certificate with one create for mydomain.com, which IS DIFFRENT than mail.mydomain.com. And cowmail has it's own certificate. Nginx should work like a bridge here.

EDIT:
Based on what djdomi suggested here what I have changed.
After removing `include /etc/nginx/tcpconf.d/*;` and appeding following code to `/etc/sites-avalible/default`. mydomain.com can be accessed but mail.mydomain.com have incorrect ssl certificate. Nginx shouldn't terminate SSL here.

```
server {
    server_name mail.mydomain.com;

    location  / {
        rewrite /(.*) /$1  break;
        proxy_pass         https://localhost:44369;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
Replaced /etc/nginx/tcpconf.d/lb with following contents:

```
stream  {
    map $ssl_preread_server_name $internalport {
        mail.mydomain.com 44369;
        default glance-no-upstream-instance;
    }

    server {
        listen 443;
        ssl_preread on;
        proxy_connect_timeout 20s;
        proxy_timeout 30s;
        proxy_pass 127.0.0.1:$internalport;
    }
}
```

Now when I try to visit mydomain.com I get "PR_END_OF_FILE_ERROR" in Firefox.
And when I vising mail.mydomain.com I actually get into my email.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite) more over, it is the way to work to use nginx for the certificate and beyond the proxy can anykind of certificates been used due nginx ignore certificate error by default any moreover I just see here reverse proxy in action....

Comment: @djdomi I am not sure how I am supposed to use that rewrite on subdomain.

Comment: I would suggest that you take a look at the question once more. it feels to me here, that you actually not have understand what you are doing in my point of view. moreover it seems like a web tutorial that misleading terms. nginx can reverse proxy anykind without a complex upstream due you only use one target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Virtual hosting** is a concept of the HTTP 1.1 protocol. The TCP protocol is not aware of the hostname, as it is communicated via the `Host:` header in HTTP, or [*Server Name Indication* (SNI)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6066.html#section-3) in HTTPS (TLS). Therefore, TCP proxies cannot be configured per hostname. They work on different layers.

But because you are proxying (**not [redirecting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Redirections)**; that's a entirely different concept of the HTTP protocol) ports `443` (HTTPS) & `80` (HTTP) it strongly suggests that it would be a [HTTP reverse proxy](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/) you need, instead. Yes, it is ok to let Nginx handle the TLS termination even in the case the back-end connection is also TLS encrypted. With the SNI you can have multiple different certificates server by the same Nginx instance.