# how configure nginx for URL rewrting scenario

Tags: nginx-reverse-proxy

i have a scenario but i do not know how to configure nginx to attain this:
the clients request "X.DOMAIN-A.XYZ" and the request goes to nginx which is configure as a reverse proxy. now the nginx must rewrite the domain as a "Z.DOMAIN-B.TRD" and forward it to origin server (upstream server).

|client|---X.DOMAIN-A.XYZ--->|nginx|---Z.DOMAIN-B.TRD--->|origin server|
i need config example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite)