# Rewrite URL and add header from the path

Tags: nginx

Hi how can I rewrite the URL from

`/context/somerandomtoken/root;id=randomid`

to this:

`/context/root;id=randomid`
then adding a request header: `Token : somerandomtoken` where `somerandomtoken` is the value in the path of the original request.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite)