# Nginx. Replace a part of URI that is proxy passed

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

I have a CMS instance that has its Admin panel hard-coded at `/admin`(`https://example.com/admin`) and it can't be changed by CMS. I thought to try Nginx to carry this task. CMS runs as a Nodejs app and served by `proxy_pass`.

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header REMOTE-HOST $remote_addr;
    add_header X-Cache $upstream_cache_status;
    proxy_connect_timeout 30s;
    proxy_read_timeout 86400s;
    proxy_send_timeout 30s;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
}
```

Would it be possible to replace `https://example.com/admin` with `https://example.com/custom` using Nginx only? Any advice is highly welcome as I don't understand where to start here.

P.S. If it matter CMS is Directus.

Upd. I tried to use [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite) but it didn't help. Here are my attempts:

```
location /foo {
  rewrite /foo/(.*) /admin/$1 break;
  proxy_pass localhost:8000;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

gave me `/foo` => `/foo/admin/login?redirect=/foo/`

```
location /foo {
  rewrite /foo/(.*) /$1 break;
  proxy_pass localhost:8000/admin;
  proxy_redirect off;
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
}
```

gave me `/foo` => `/admin/foo`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nginx reverse proxy + URL rewrite](https://serverfault.com/questions/379675/nginx-reverse-proxy-url-rewrite)

Comment: I couldn't apply. Tried this `
    location /foo {
        rewrite /foo/(.*) /admin/$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }
`

and received this URI `foo/admin/login?redirect=/foo/`

Tried this

```
    location /foo {
        rewrite /foo/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/admin;
        proxy_redirect     off;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
    }
```

And git this URI `admin/foo`

Comment: Comments don't allow multiline code blocks, sorry.

Comment: don't use commentary section to respond changes, please update the question instead please

Comment: updated the question